# React - async function in useEffect ends up in a loop

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks, recoiljs

Even after some time using React I still do not get sometimes why it behaves the way it behaves.

I am trying set the company that I get from the DB if user doesn't have it saved in the state. (I use react recoil for state management)
State can be either null or CompanyModel:

```
const [company, setCompany] = useState(companyState.companyDetails);
const companyActions = useCompanyActions();

...

useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Company: ', company)
        if (!company) {
            const companyId: string | null = searchParams.get("companyId")
            if (companyId) {
                companyActions.getCompany(companyId).then((result) => {
                    if (result) {
                        setCompany(result)
                    } else {
                        navigate('/portfolio');
                    }
                }).catch((e) => {
                    navigate('/portfolio');
                })
            } else {
                navigate('/portfolio');
            }
        }
}, [company])
```

Company Actions:

```
async function getCompany(companyId: string) {
    try {
      const result = await CalyxApi.companyApi().companyControllerGetCompany(companyId)
      setCompany((state) => ({
        ...state,
        companyProfile: result.data,
        companyDetails: result.data.company
      }));
      return result.data.company
    } catch (e) {
      errorSuccessActions.throwError(e);
      return;
    }
 }
```

So first I check if company is in the state. If not I get the url parameter with company id and fetch the company. The problem comes with setCompany. It always result in this error: `Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.`

I aproached it in couple of different ways but error remains the same. So instead of setting the company after fetching it I just set the loading state first:

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (!company) {
            setLoading(true)
            const companyId: string | null = searchParams.get("companyId")
            if (companyId) {
                companyActions.getCompany(companyId).then((result) => {
                    if (result) {
                        setLoading(false)
                    } else {
                        navigate('/portfolio');
                    }
                }).catch((e) => {
                    navigate('/portfolio');
                })
            } else {
                navigate('/portfolio');
            }
        }
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
        setCompany(companyState.companyDetails)
    }, [companyState.companyDetails])
```

Since getCompany is Company Actions is already setting recoil state I just read it in a different useEffect and try to set it there, but it result in the same error again.

I tried to change the getCompany to something like this, but it made no difference:

```
 return CalyxApi.companyApi().companyControllerGetCompany(companyId).then((result) => {
      setCompany((state) => ({
        ...state,
        companyProfile: result.data,
        companyDetails: result.data.company
      }));
      return result.data.company
    }).catch((e) => {
      errorSuccessActions.throwError(e);
 })
```

I also tried not to set any state in the component and simply read data from recoil state. Something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (!companyState.companyDetails) {
            setLoading(true)
            const companyId: string | null = searchParams.get("companyId")
            if (companyId) {
                companyActions.getCompany(companyId).then((result) => {
                    if (result) {
                        setLoading(false)
                    } else {
                        navigate('/portfolio');
                    }
                }).catch((e) => {
                    navigate('/portfolio');
                })
            } else {
                navigate('/portfolio');
            }
        }
    }, [])

useEffect(() => {}, [companyState.companyDetails])
```

And also just having one useEffect with the state check:

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (!companyState.companyDetails) {
            setLoading(true)
            const companyId: string | null = searchParams.get("companyId")
            if (companyId) {
                companyActions.getCompany(companyId).then((result) => {
                    if (result) {
                        setLoading(false)
                    } else {
                        navigate('/portfolio');
                    }
                }).catch((e) => {
                    navigate('/portfolio');
                })
            } else {
                navigate('/portfolio');
            }
        }
    }, [companyState.companyDetails])
```

But again the same error happens. At this point I am not even sure if I understand the problem and the way react handles states anymore. The error says that this can be due to dependency changing on every render. I made sure other actions do not set the CompanyModel to undefined or null.
The code works when CompanyModel is already set in the state, but the moment I reload it breaks.
I made sure the url parameter is there. I tried to not set any state in useEffect at all. Nothing works and everytime I get the same error.

Comment: Okay so new finding. In my getCompany action i set state in recoil with two values. One for companyProfile and one for companyDetails. For some reason companyDetail state cause the error. I'm not yet sure why but when I comment it out then at least it's not causing the error at all and I can get the same data from companyProfile. 
Will investigate further but at least it's not breaking anymore

Answer (score 0):

since the fetch is dependent on companyId, may be you can try creating a companyId varaible

the idea is since the company id will be unique it wont trigger useEffect

```
 const companyId = companyState.companyDetails ? 
 searchParams.get("companyId") : null

  useEffect(() => {

     let invalidScope = false

     if (!companyId) {
       return;
     }
   
     const fetchData = async () => {

       const companyData = await companyActions.getCompany(companyId)
       if (invalidScope) {
          return;
       }

       //use the companyData to update state

     }

     fetchData()

     return  () => {
        invalidScope = true;
     }

  }, [companyId])
```

or it could be the case that companyActions.getCompany is causing a rerender of the child

Comment: So I found the reason for the problem and it's not a problem with recoil or react useEffect or the async function. It was actually formik library I use for validating fields. It has a useFormik hook where you can set initialValues. I am not sure how formik handles this, but I was setting two values with a ternary operation and that was messing everything up. So instead I set initialValue withtout any conditions and later use formik.setFieldValue after getting company. 
Now everything works.